# 'And' appears to return 'true' when 'true and false' (when answer == b, answer != a && b returns true)

Tags: javascript

I cannot figure out why this doesn't work. If I enter "No" into the prompt, I am given the same prompt again, meaning the do loop executed again because the while statement returned true. According to my logic however, when the answer "No" is given, the while statement should return false and end the do loop. When (answer != "Yes") is true and (answer != "No") is false, shouldn't the "and" operator with one true operand and one false operand return false (true && false == false)? What am I getting wrong here? Everything else works.

```
do {
  var answer = prompt("Do you want dinner? Yes or No."); 
} while (answer != "Yes" && "No");
if (answer == "Yes") {
  alert("Great, there is food in the fridge!"); }
else {
  alert("Ok. I will ask again later."); }
```

Comment: What does `"Yes" && "No"` do?

Comment: @PHPglue No, `answer != "Yes" && "No"` evaluates to false (when answer is 'Yes') or 'No'

Comment: @PHPglue That is what I would think too. But in practice, it seems to evaluate to false when the answer is "Yes", but true when the answer is "No"

Comment: The `&&` operator can't be used to list alternative values to test against the `!=`. Your while condition `answer != "Yes" && "No"` is like saying `(answer != "Yes") && "No"`.

Comment: @Jordan `"Yes" && "No"` evaluates to `"No"`, but your code doesn't contain `"Yes" && "No"` as a subexpression, only `(answer != "Yes") && "No"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function logAnswer(answer) {
  console.log(answer != "Yes" && "No");
}

logAnswer("Wub") --> false && true --> false
logAnswer("Yes") --> false && true --> false
logAnswer("No")  --> true && true  --> true
```

`&& "No"` will evaluate the string "No" as truthy. There should be two evaluations of `answer`. Personally I think an OR operator might read better here.

```
while (!(answer == "Yes" || answer == "No"))  // OR operator
while (answer != "Yes" && answer != "No")    // AND operator
```

Answer (score 3):

The while condition is wrong. The second part will always be true.

Try this:

```
while (answer != "Yes" && answer != "No");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition form was wrong.

```
do {
  var answer = prompt("Do you want dinner? Yes or No."); 
} while (answer != "Yes" && answer != "No");
if (answer == "Yes") {
  alert("Great, there is food in the fridge!"); }
else {
  alert("Ok. I will ask again later."); }
```

Answer (score -2):

You must write a complete test on both sides of `&&`. `"No"` will always evaluate to `true`.

```
while (answer != "Yes" && answer != "No")
```